# OLS Multiple Regression with Constrained Coefficients in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

First introduced as “Effective Asset Mix Analysis” by Sharpe (1988, 1992). Given a time series of returns of a fund, we try to find the mix of market indices that most closely fits the fund returns

Rt =Σj=1t on WjRjt +εt

Rt is the return on the fund during period t
Wj is the weight of index j
Rjt is the return on index j during period t N is the number of indices
εt is the residual for period t Sum of Wj =1, 0<Wj<1

The linear regression looks like this:

`lm(Return~RMRF+SMB+HML+RMW+CMA+WML)`
sum of w1 + w2 +w3+ w4+ w5 + w6 must be equal to 1 & 0<W1<1, 0<W2<1, 0<W3<1, 0<W4<1, 0<W5<1, 0<W6<1

```
RMRF<-seq(0.1, 0.38, 0.01)

SMB<-seq(0.567, 3.43, 0.1)

HML<-c(0.2779847,   8.0264832,   5.3220615,   6.0018334,  -1.6453088,   0.8797469, -11.7401832,  6.6918100,  13.4933761, 29.4326627,  15.4784988,  12.7620389,  8.6609398,  13.5182957,  10.5642555,  16.2769744,  10.5017521,   6.8056429, 4.2213311,   3.9782718,   3.0807381,  -1.1463134,  -1.6779659,   2.1594784,   0.3175780,  -1.3537170,  -6.0749482, -14.1179519,  -7.1843946)

CMA<-c(4.4861560,  5.2225740,   5.0143182,   4.3095509,  -4.6995774,  -5.9131464 ,-18.6426615,  -8.4720251 , -8.8441047, 7.9143735,   4.7228250,   2.3323631,   0.7291851,   0.2228563,   4.5186684,  15.2056919,   8.6473266,   6.9853941, -3.5298969,   2.9377347,   1.0234615,   1.2489909,   0.4876903,   0.2682861,   0.4223881,  -1.2420955,  -2.7008911, -8.7600239,  -4.3200991)

WML<-c(1.2652667,  -4.9939866,  -9.3409655,  -7.8398924,   7.5834817,   5.2052111,  26.1681918,  -0.7340554,  14.2993323, -4.7537949,  -0.6015832,  -5.6729850,  1.0444217,  7.7401486,   8.1841650,   8.3217436,  -4.9279098,  -8.8318481, -13.0344319,   1.1946743,   7.6068103,   4.7373327,   4.3619793,  -5.6985077,  -1.1614607,  -2.7103998,  -0.6407941,  -1.7205889,  -3.5596958)

Return<-c(0.254833800,  0.529037900,  0.515281900, -0.051242010, -1.086244000, -0.244727100,  0.011298250, -0.006221349, -0.624509200, -0.816637000,  0.292818100,  0.813584700,  0.279639600, -0.325332300, -0.427709900, -0.486177300,  0.156662800,  0.834633400, 0.710158400,  0.502986200, -0.066646120, -0.581395500, -0.511287100,  0.335159300,  0.661496000,  0.439663200,  0.489402600, 0.053834020,  0.079386050)

RMW<-seq(0.06, 0.34, 0.01)

library(data.table)
table<-data.table(Return, RMRF, HML, CMA, SMB, WML, RMW)
```

Comment: are `w` the coefficients? if so you do not include them when doing a regression unless you are doing non-linear least squares

Comment: @onyambu yes, I edited it. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: This is not OLS. Consider using NLS. Or you could post your data

Comment: @onyambu I have added a picture of my data, how could I share It differently?

Comment: share it as text. or simply paste the `dput(data)`

Comment: @onyambu shared it as text in description, you can copy it directly into R